# Hexadecimal alpha variable?

Tags: colors, processing, hex

I'm having trouble with my Hexadecimal values. I'm trying find a way so as the alpha of my HEX changes over time.

Right now my code looks like:

```
color c = 0X00202020;
```

Trying to change the'0x00" to a var as to allow it to be more easily manipulated. I have tried...

```
int alph = 00; 


color = 0xalph202020;
```

Obviously this does not work.

Is there any other way to use variables inside of a HEX?

I really don’t want to convert the values to RGB. Hoping to find a solution.

Comment: Next time try look it up on default Processing [reference page](http://www.processing.org/reference/color_datatype.html)

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention which language. In most you can "bit shift".
e.g.

```c
int red = 0x20;
int green = 0x20;
int blue = 0x20;
int alpha = 0;

// Shift the alpha value "left" by 24 bits, red by 16 and green by 8.
// Assumes that each value is just 8bits long (0-255)
//
int color = (alpha << 24) + (red << 16) + (green <<8) + blue;
```

Comment: Sorry I'm using Processing... still quite new to it. Havent come accross bit shifting yet but I'll look it up

Comment: Looks like processing works pretty much as above: https://www.processing.org/reference/leftshift.html

Answer (score 0):

Best way to change only alpha value of your color is using 'color()' methode with hexadecimal value so you do not need to convert value into RGB:

```
color c = color(0x00202020, alph);
```